# How do I format the date before updating in Laravel, using vuejs-datepicker

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am using vuejs-datepicker and inertiajs, but when I try to update the database I am getting the error:
Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '2021-07-09T12:54:00.000Z' for column 'date_of_birth'

I tried formatting the date within the controller, but this doesn't save anything. What am I missing here?

eidt.vue:

```
<datepicker v-model="form.date_of_birth" name="Date of birth" />

data() {
      return {
        form: this.$inertia.form({
          _method: 'put',
          date_of_birth: this.application.date_of_birth,
        }),
      }
},

methods: {
      update() {
          this.form.put(this.route('applications.update', this.application.id))
      },
},
```

controller/applications.update:

```
User::find($application->user_id)->update(Request::only(
     ['date_of_birth' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $application->user->date_of_birth)],
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```php
User::find($application->user_id)
    ->update([
        'date_of_birth' => Carbon::parse(request()->date_of_birth)->toDateTimeString()
    ]);
```

Depending on how the date is coming from the front end, you need to parse `date_of_birth` to a date time string which will be accepted by the database.

This can be done by using the `Carbon::parse($value)->toDateTimeString()` method above.

Make sure to import `Carbon` into the controller:

`use Carbon\Carbon`

Answer (score 1):

This is how we do it, for every datepicker date in the form we make a setter on the model e.g.

```
public function setDateOfBirthAttribute($value): void
{
    $this->attributes['date_of_birth'] = $value ? Carbon::parse($value) : null;
}
```